# How do I install Fedora Silverblue on Raspberry Pi 4?

Tags: pi-4, software-installation, fedora

I haven't been able to find instructions on how to install Fedora Silverblue on a Raspberry Pi 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one method to install and boot via EDK2. You will need a USB device and the target installation medium (either another USB or microSD card).

0. Make sure your Raspberry Pi firmware is up to date.

Perform the following steps using a computer:

1. Install the Silverblue Live ISO on the USB device.
   (Fedora's recommended method is to use `mediawriter`)
2. Plug-in the target install device and create an EFI system partition (ESP) on it.
   (replace sdX with your device, be **careful** to select the correct device as this can **wipe all data**)

   ```bash
   sudo mkfs.vfat /dev/sdX
   ```
3. Mount the ESP.

   ```bash
   mkdir /tmp/ESP
   sudo mount /dev/sdX /tmp/ESP
   ```
4. Copy and unzip the latest firmware from https://github.com/pftf/RPi4/releases into the mounted directory.
5. Unmount the ESP and eject the devices from the computer.

   ```bash
   sudo umount /tmp/ESP
   ```

With the Raspberry Pi:

6. Plug both (1) the USB with the Silverblue Live ISO and (2) your target device into the Raspberry Pi
7. Boot the Raspberry Pi and press Escape to bring up the boot menu
8. Follow the below navigation to remove the `3GB RAM Limit` by changing the default `Enabled` to `Disabled`.
   `Device Manager` → `Raspberry Pi Configuration` → `Advanced Configuration`
9. The Live ISO should boot and you can install Silverblue to the target device.
10. Remove both devices.

Perform the following steps using a computer:

11. Plug in the target device with Silverblue installed and mount the EFI system partition.
    (replace sdX with your device)

    ```bash
    sudo mount $(sudo fdisk -l /dev/sdX | awk '/EFI/ { print $1; }') /tmp/ESP
    ```
12. Copy the latest firmware from Step `4` into the EFI system partition.
13. Unmount the EFI system partition.

    ```bash
    sudo umount /tmp/ESP
    ```

At this point you should be able to plugin the Silverblue installation into the Raspberry Pi and it should boot properly. Enjoy!

Additional resource:
https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/fedora-coreos/provisioning-raspberry-pi4/#_installing_fcos_and_booting_via_edk2

Comment: I'd like to install with LUKS encrypted volume. Is it possible to do?